# Filling the details in a third party website automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cors

I have a page with an iframe (displaying a third party website) in it. On click of a button in my page, username which I feed in, should go and get set in that third party website, from my iframe. I have been trying this for a while and have read about **'Same Origin Policy'** and thus have been trying to use '**CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)**'. I don't know if whatever am trying is allowed, but this is what I have done till now.

I do not know how to proceed from here.

```
<iframe name="ifr" id="ifr" height="200" width="200" src="https://somethirdPartyWebsite.com"/> </iframe><br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="validate()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    var request = createCORSRequest("get", "https://ala.kcpl.com/ala/mainLogin.cfm");
    alert("request-->"+request);
    if (request){
        request.onload = function() {
            alert("In onload...");
        };
        request.onreadystatechange = stateChanged();
        request.send();
    }
}

function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

function stateChanged(){
    alert("State Changed..");
}
```

**OUTPUT : **In IE, am getting alert("request-->"), alert("State Changed"), alert("In load").

In Firefox, am getting alert("request-->"), alert("State Changed").

**Question:** What am I to conclude from this and how do I go forward and set the value in the text field of the third party website, which is present in the iframe **ifr**

I think I need to do something like

```
$("#ifr").contents().find('#inputUsername').val()="ValueToEnter".
```

Not familiar with UI coding, please don't frown :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Same-origin policy doesn't allow this.

CORS should be set on the server-side, it's not something that you can configure client-side.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do from the client side to auto fill the fields of a cross platform or 3rd party? So unless the server gives us permission to its contents, get/post requests cannot be done?

Comment: One option is disabling the browser's same-origin rules, here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome.

Comment: " So unless the server gives us permission to its contents, get/post requests cannot be done?". If you are using client-side JavaScript for communicating with an external API, yes, browser doesn't allow this. Browser sends a preflight (using the HTTP OPTIONS verb) to the server, if the server allows the request, then the actual request is sent.

Comment: If I successfully disable the policy, how do I proceed?

Comment: For updating the field you should use the `val` as a setter, your last snippet won't work: `$("#ifr").contents().find('#inputUsername').val("ValueToEnter");`.

Comment: So this last line should go into function StateChanged() ? Or in    request.onload = function() {
            alert("In onload...");
        };

Comment: You don't need the code snippets that you have posted in your question , the above jQuery snippet is enough for accessing an input in an iframe and updating it's value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93219/discussion-between-anuj-balan-and-vohuman).

Comment: Disabling the same origin did the trick. Thank you so much. 5 hours of pain.